# How can I directly convert docx to ePub in PHP?

Tags: php, epub

Trying to find a PHP library that will enable me to convert docx to ePub.

I'm aware of Java solutions (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/epub-tools/), and PHP classes used to create ePub files (e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/oplsepublibrary/).

But what I'm looking for is a direct conversion from docx (or PDF at a  push) to ePub using PHP.

Is anyone aware of solution that can achieve this?

**EDIT**

I have added a link in my answer below to a solution that I have developed to achieve this.
The solution is available on Github at:
https://github.com/benskay/PHP-Digital-Format-Convert-Epub-Mobi-PDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I haven't been able to find a direct solution for this, I have found the following simple solution for converting from docx to ePub.

- Firstly, use [PHPDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) to export xHTML from the docx file
- Then, use the [EPub class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6115-PHP-Create-ebook-in-EPUB-format-for-ex-Apple-iPad.html) to convert the exported HTML into an ePub file.

An example of this is available here:

https://github.com/benskay/PHP-Digital-Format-Convert-Epub-Mobi-PDF

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that the only direct solution to convert from DOCX to EPUB is [the .NET component made by Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx).

One possible indirect way (I've not tested this):

- Convert DOCX to DocBook XML (See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332446/convert-word-docx-to-docbook) - I think that you can control OpenOffice server with PHP).
- Use the [DocBook XSLT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/files/docbook-xsl/) to convert DocBook XML to EPUB (can be made with PHP, see libxslt).