# Refer a Document from a desktop application in java

Tags: java

I have an application which consist of menu's.In the help menu i have tutorial menuitem.What i want to do is when i click the menuitem "tutorial" a document in the application directory need to be opened.Can i acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)` method.

See [Desktop API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) and [Using the Desktop API in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/).

Comment: Hi i am referring tutorial.doc in the file.But when the application is runned on mac the extension with doc doesn't exist.How can i overcome this

Comment: @hemanth You'd better try to avoid using `.doc` files if you want MAC support. For example, you can convert doc to HTML. See [convert-doc-docx-to-semantic-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335412/convert-doc-docx-to-semantic-html) for details.

Comment: i have diagrams in my document can i still convert my doc to html?

Comment: hey sorry about the question, mac  supports the .doc files.

Comment: @hemanth Would you mind to give me the link to the source of your info about .doc support. I'm still not acquainted with mac os.

Comment: @hemanth Yep. You can use [java.io.File.setReadOnly()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly()).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the document. You could give the [`Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class a try. From the docs: *"The Desktop class allows a Java application to launch associated applications registered on the native desktop to handle a URI or a file."*. Note that you need at least java 6 for this.

If that doesn't work, you could also use one of the various `exec(...)` methods from the [`Runtime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class. But it has quite a bit of pitfalls, this document describes them: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class from the Java standard Library to let the OS launch the proper application to view the document. Call the `open` method to view the document.